# Need open source HRM which can be integrated with liferay

Tags: java, liferay

We are developing our own intranet portal. We are developing it on liferay. Can you please suggest us that are there any open source HRMs which can be integrated with liferay or which exposes Java APIs?

Comment: sorry to ask this, but what do you mean by hrm? My first guess is Human resource management?

Comment: perhaps you could provide a list of features you require, i have not learned of any open source java frameworks or anything like this concerning hrm

Comment: Here are some, you have to check to see to customize them to your needs: 1) [Time Trex](https://www.timetrex.com/download.php) 2) [Waypoint-HR](http://waypointhr.com/) 3) [Open Applicant](http://www.openapplicant.org/index.html)